# Isomorphic relation between dihedral groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, examples-counterexamples, dihedral-groups

> Theorem
>
> Let $G,H$ be abelian groups such that $Dih(G)\cong Dih(H)$
>
> If $G$ is finitely generated, then $G\cong H$.

I'm curious whether "finitely generated" hypothesis can be removed.

If it's not true in general, what would be a counterexample?

=====

EDIT:

The below statement is equivalent to the above question.

> Let $G,H$ be abelian groups such that every element of $G,H$ is of order 2.
>
> If $G\times Z_2 \cong H\times Z_2$ (direct product), then $G\cong H$.

Is this statement true?

Comment: How is $Dih(G)$ defined?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft $Dih(G)=G\rtimes Z_2$ where the homomorphism $Z_2\rightarrow Aut(G)$ is given by inversion. (As in wikipedia page for : Generalized dihedral group)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your second question, there is no need to assume that $G,H$ are abelian, because all groups in which every element has order $2$ are abelian! Such groups are vector spaces over the field of order $2$, so the groups $G$ and $H$ in your question are subspaces of $G \times C_2$, and they clearly have the same dimension, so they are isomorphic.